# Create Container class in redux typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I currently follow a tutorial for redux and typescript.

Because I love object-oriented programming compared to functional programming, therefore, I decided to create a container-widget abstract class But I am quite confused how to convert it.

Original Code:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { setVisibilityFilter } from '../actions'
import Link from '../components/Link'

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    active: ownProps.filter === state.visibilityFilter
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onClick: () => {
      dispatch(setVisibilityFilter(ownProps.filter))
    }
  }
}

const FilterLink = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Link)

export default FilterLink
```

Converted Code (So Far):

```
import {State} from "./State";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as React from "react";

export abstract class Container {

    abstract mapStateToProps(state : State) : any;

    abstract mapDispatchToProps(dispatch : any) : any;

    constructor(connector : React.ComponentClass<any>) {
        connect(
            this.mapStateToProps,
            this.mapDispatchToProps
        )(connector);
    }
}
```

Later, I will extend the container using this abstract class.
For example:

```
class LoginForm extends Container {

}
```

In the other component

```
render() {
    <App><LoginForm></LoginForm></App>
}
```

Comment: Simple way to answer it is: the thing that you will render as `<LoginForm/>` must be a thing that is returned when you call `connect`. So your constructor shall look smth like `this.connected = connect( ...`, and then you render like `<LoginForm.connected/>`

Comment: Very doubtful profit.

Comment: The initial approach imho also is, just trying to help to understand what needs to be used as a renderer. Can't think of profitable scenario here at all

Comment: @jevgenig it's was about the initial approach

Comment: LoginForm.connected seems to be redundant, is there any better approach?

Comment: Javascript currently lacks conversion operators, thus you cannot describe `Container` => `React.ComponentClass` conversion, to be able to use smth like `public static implicit operator React.ComponentClass(Container container) { return container.connected; }` and keep using it as `<LoginForm/>`. Thus, anything you want to render like `<anything/>` has to be a variable

Comment: **Do not do this**. The statement `Because I love object-oriented programming compared to functional programming, therefore, I decided to create a container-widget abstract class But I am quite confused how to convert it` implies a flawed endeavor. Adding a hierarchy for its own sake is a bad enough idea in an OO framework.

Comment: Also, quit it with the `any`s. Either specify a proper type, such as `{}`, or turn off `--noImplicitAny`. You are making your code worse with them.

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes the any type is not done yet, i am building my own library currently.

Comment: @AluanHaddad so i have to stay with the functional programming?

Comment: Wah, this is bad news @jevgenig, thanks anw

Comment: @AluanHaddad you are welcome. And it's not like 100% sticking to functional programming. You can still enjoy OOP building Components and Containers using React.Components, but yes, great part of react-redux-immutable approaches at the moment, are functional.

Comment: how to enjoy building container in react.components with oop? (with redux) since this is what i am trying to solve because i feel something is lacking without the power of oop

Comment: @RobertLimanto actually functional programming is more powerful, especially in this language because many constructs are higher order/first class. Consider that `class` is higher order in ECMAScript. Also, TypeScript's type system is at least as functional as it is object oriented, and new features continue to enhance patterns involving function composition.

Comment: If you're trying to add a reusable "visibilityFilter" to your components,  the [Higher Order Component)(https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) pattern is the usual way of doing this.  You *could* create a rigid abstract class hierarchy, but it will be much messier when you later try to combine different pieces of functionality together.  Well-designed HOCs add functionality by stacking, so you can mix-and-match them, horizontally.